# Excel VBA UserForm filter using CheckBoxes and past the matching cells to a new sheet

Tags: excel, vba, filter, checkbox, userform

I'm a complete beginner to VBA and I'm currently trying to do a UserForm for filtering lines containing checkboxes, linked to each cell, giving TRUE/FALSE values.
I want to have checkboxes on the UserForm and keyword search as well.

The data origin is a table on a separate sheet. Columns C-T are the filter criterias, which are set when putting data in the table.
Column B is the actual content, it's raw text and it's what I want to get filtered.
Column A is just for the current number of each line.

On the UserForm I'll have checkboxes with the same names as the columns C-T and when I check some of them and click the filter button, I want Excel to paste the text from B of each matching line to a second spreadsheet.

I also want to search with keywords as optional addition - but this is nothing important.

I hope it's understandable.

[image]

I already have some code for creating the captions of the checkboxes in the userform automatically based on the column names and the reset button for clearing the userform is working, too.

The code for captions:

```
Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    CheckBox1.Caption = Sheets("Datenbank").Range("C1").Value
    CheckBox2.Caption = Sheets("Datenbank").Range("D1").Value
    CheckBox3.Caption = Sheets("Datenbank").Range("E1").Value
    CheckBox4.Caption = Sheets("Datenbank").Range("F1").Value
    CheckBox5.Caption = Sheets("Datenbank").Range("G1").Value
    CheckBox6.Caption = Sheets("Datenbank").Range("H1").Value
    CheckBox7.Caption = Sheets("Datenbank").Range("I1").Value
    CheckBox8.Caption = Sheets("Datenbank").Range("J1").Value
    CheckBox9.Caption = Sheets("Datenbank").Range("K1").Value
    CheckBox10.Caption = Sheets("Datenbank").Range("L1").Value
    CheckBox11.Caption = Sheets("Datenbank").Range("M1").Value
    CheckBox12.Caption = Sheets("Datenbank").Range("N1").Value
    CheckBox13.Caption = Sheets("Datenbank").Range("O1").Value
    CheckBox14.Caption = Sheets("Datenbank").Range("P1").Value
    CheckBox15.Caption = Sheets("Datenbank").Range("Q1").Value
    CheckBox16.Caption = Sheets("Datenbank").Range("R1").Value
    CheckBox17.Caption = Sheets("Datenbank").Range("S1").Value
    CheckBox18.Caption = Sheets("Datenbank").Range("T1").Value
End Sub
```

The code for the reset button:

```
Sub Reset()
    Dim c As Control
    For Each c In UserForm1.Controls
        If TypeName(c) = "TextBox" Then
            c.Value = ""
        End If
    Next c
    Dim d As Control
        For Each d In UserForm1.Controls
        If TypeName(d) = "CheckBox" Then
            d.Value = "False"
        End If
    Next d
End Sub
```

Is anyone here able to help?

Answer (score 0):

goto developer tab and you must see record macro whis smail red squre and behind vba node
1- click on it
2- name it
3- do as you do to normall applay filter on each column it that sheet
4- stop macro recoding
5 - press on macro you will see the macro you just recording
now select it and press edit you will see the vba code for filtring
hop this work for you
sheref adel

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).